# Set specific Redis DB for FunWithFlagsUI?

Tags: redis, elixir

### Background

We are using [FunWithFlagsUI](https://github.com/tompave/fun_with_flags_ui) to check the flags we have on our Redis instance. Since Redis has several DBs one can choose from, this raises a problem - we need to tell the UI which Redis DB to use.

### Problem

After reading the docs, I couldn't find any option to do that. By default, the UI will always read from Redis DB 1, which is not where our flags are.

Is there a way to tell the UI which Redis DB to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what do you mean by the UI, but it seems you can configure redis database on the config adding a database option:

```
config :fun_with_flags, :redis, database: 1
```

Comment: The package is called FunWithFlagsUI, and it configures the UI to be used with FunWithFlags. It allows you to have a Phoenix endpoint and configurations to access a webpage that displays the flags information.